# A nice way to split a Range in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following code, is there any way to simplify this to more a beautify way?

```
var i = 0
val step = 100
val limitArr = new ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)]
while (i < rddPartNumber) {
   limitArr += ((i, i + step))
   i += step
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing is basically looping over a sequence of numbers.  That can be expressed by mapping on a `Range`

```
val limits = (0 until rddPartNumber by step) map {i => (i , i + step)}
```

Or if you prefer `for` syntax

```
for {i <- 0 until rddPartNumber by step}
yield (i, i + step)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> val range = 0 to rddPartNumber  by step
scala> range.zip(range.tail)
```

With `step` equal to 100 and `rddPartNumber` equal to 1000

`res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((0,100), (100,200), (200,300), (300,400), (400,500), (500,600), (600,700), (700,800), (800,900), (900,1000))`

If you really need an `Array`, add a `toArray` after zipping them together.

Comment: This is nice and compact... but perhaps confusing! If `zip` is called with two lists of differing length then the excess elements are ignored. Because tail will be of n-1 length of `range`, no tuple will be generated for the last element at the 1st spot of the tuple and a total of n-1 tuples will be generated

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.tabulate` for an interval from `a` to `rddPartNumber` as follows

```
Array.tabulate((rddPartNumber-a)/step) { i => (i*step, i*step+step) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
scala> val range = 0 to 444 by 100
range: scala.collection.immutable.Range = inexact Range 0 to 444 by 100

scala> (range zip range.tail).toArray
res0: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,100), (100,200), (200,300), (300,400))
```

`444` is just a placeholder for `rddPartNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the range function to build a list with the step size you want and then map the list to build the tuples:

```
val list = List.range(0, rddPartNumber, step) // List(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, ...)

val tuples = list.map(x => (x, x + step)) // List((0,100), (100,200), (200,300), (300,400), (400,500), (500,600)

val array = tuples.toArray
```